# How to get road direction vector from coordinate input to google maps api or directions api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap

I am working on a project that requires I plot markers at metropolitan coordinates via the Google Maps API.  I can plot the markers just fine and draw polygons easily, but I need to draw polygons parallel to the road common to each coordinate and if possible, find traffic direction.  Each coordinate input is verified to be next to a road in a a downtown metropolitan area.  Is it possible to get that information from the Google Maps API or open streets API?

A sample coordinate is [47.6018, -122.314].

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: What information are you trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple [online routers](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/OnlineRouters) based on OpenStreetMap data availabe. Several of them offer a GPX export. Try for example [OSRM](http://map.project-osrm.org/) or [graphhopper](http://graphhopper.com/).